# Android ListView items loose listener if too many items added

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview on which I have `onItemLongClickListener` attached. Everything works fine but when I add too many (e.g. 100) items to the list, some of the views lose the listener. Not sure what the problem is, I also debugged the problem and still can't figure it out.

There is no exception being thrown either, it just stops working.

Then if I remove everything from the list and start to add things, it works fine as long as I don't add to many item.

Is it the memory issue?

I searched around everywhere but no luck.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_frame);

    // Set text view for orderTotal
    orderTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
    orderTotal.setText("0.00");
    // List view from layout
    itemsListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.item_list);
    // Current order to be consistent throughout activities.
    currentOrder = ((OrderIt)this.getApplication()).getCurrentOrder();

    databaseCategories = (ArrayList<Category>) this.getIntent().getExtras()
            .getSerializable("databaseCategories");
    // List of items already in order.
    itemsListView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,
            currentOrder.getItems()));

    itemsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);


    this.registerForContextMenu(itemsListView);
    // Gridview from layout
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.item_grid);
    ArrayList<Item> items = getItems();
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, items));
    // Set click adapter to grid view items
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);          

}
```

Comment: Are you doing something extra in your adapter? Hijacking events there? It shouldn't be a problem adding too many items. I can't think of any reason why that would be happening.

Comment: no nothing fancy in adapter either, just inflating view and assigning values to items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution to the problem,

I was asking

```
adapterView.getChildAt(position)
```

which is not right way to do it if you looking to get underneath data,

right way is to call

```
adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

which returns underneath object which was used to populate listView.

Answer (score 0):

I think:
Your item contains the EditText or Button which vies auto get focus from the item or listView.
you need to setFocus(false) or listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
let the item views can't take the focus.

Comment: no, listItem does not contain EditText or Button, it only have TextView and ImageView